# Cannot connect to Bank Of America via Plaid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, connection, account, plaid, bank

While connecting to Bank of America via Plaid, a `Account not currently supported. Your account is not currently supported. Please log in to a different account` message is displayed.
Plaid connection is working for Chase.

I'm using `plaid-ruby` to integrate Plaid.

[Plaid Account not supported message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sEpHZ.png)

Could this be because of Multi Factor Authentication or something else?

Answer (score 0):

What's the actual error code? You can see it in the Dashboard activity log.

Hard to diagnose this without the error code but I'm going to take a guess -- are you not yet approved for production access or were approved for production really recently?  Bank of America connections require Production approval plus a few extra days wait time.